# Find palindrome from multiple files

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R Programming Language.

I have to read around 100 txt files and read comma separated values from it. Those values are in the following format - "Name", "Gender", "Count" and "Year".

I am able to do that...

## PROBLEM:

I need to parse every name of that file and find if that is palindrome or not.

I have tried several methods, but couldn't able to do that.

## Code:

```
list_of_files <- list.files(pattern = '.txt') 
counter = 1879
result_palindrom = 0
inter_palindrom = 0
# Function which checks if a word is palindrom or not
is_palindrome <- function(word){
  charsplit <- strsplit(word, "")[[1]]
  revchar <- rev(charsplit)
  all(charsplit==revchar)
}

# We need to append all the data into one file
for (year in 1880:1970){
  cur_data = read.table(list_of_files[year-counter],header = FALSE,sep = ",", col.names = c("name","sex","count"), fill = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
  cur_data$year <- year
  cur_data = cur_data[,c(4,1,2,3)]
  cur_data$palindrom = cur_data[is_palindrome(cur_data$name), ]
  inter_palindrom = rbind(inter_palindrom, cur_data)
}

print(inter_palindrom)
```

## Error Message

```
Error in strsplit(word, "") : non-character argument
Called from: strsplit(word, "")
```

Can anyone please help me?

## Data Looks like this:

```
Name | Sex | Count | Year
X       M      100    1880
Y       F      80     1884
Z       M      90     1882
```

All data for different year is in separate year's file

Comment: That simply means you passed a non-character argument to `strsplit`.   It needs to be character.  Try  `as.character(word)` there.

Comment: I did charsplit <- strsplit(as.character(word), "")[[1]]
that gave me following error:

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "palindrom", value = list(year = integer(0),  : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 2000

Comment: Other than that we can't really help you until a reproducible example is provided.

Comment: Given sample data, I am good to read files and store in data frames. I am capturing all data into single data frame, and thinking of adding new palindrom column as well. which will have 1 or 0 based on if it is palindrom or not